# Prove that $P$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ with dimension $n$. Let {$u_1$$,...,u_n$} and {$w_1$$,...,w_n$} be bases for $W$. Let $P=(p_{i,j})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $$w_i=\sum_{j=1}^n p_{j,i}u_j=p_{1,i}u_1+...+p_{n,i}u_n, 1\leq i\leq n,$$ i.e. $(w_1 w_2...w_n)=(u_1 u_2 ... u_n)P$ as a block matrix multiplication.
Equivalently, $W=UP$ where columns of matrix $W$ are $w_1,...w_n,$ and the columns of matrix $U$ are $u_1,...,u_n$. Prove that $P$ is invertible.

I'd like to ask how to write $u_k$ as a linear combination of $w_1,...,w_n$, for each $k, 1\leq k \leq n$? How to solve this problem?

Comment: P is the change of basis matrix. P is the matrix representation of Identity map from W with one basis to W with other basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basis of your space, so you can define also the change base matrix $Q$ such that

$U=WQ$

using the same definition of the matrix $P$ but changing the order of the two basis.

But you have also $W=UP$ and so

$W=W(QP)$

that means $I=QP$, so that $P$ is an invertibile matrix